# Cell won't show on UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView ViewController in my application.
I created a custom cell for it, but the cell won't show.
This is my VC:

```
class NotificationVC: UICollectionViewController{

let cellId = "notificationCell"
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.setNavBar()
    navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("notification.vc.title", comment: "Notification")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.appWhite

    setupCollectionView()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//MARK: -- CollectionView setup
fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.appWhite
    self.collectionView!.register(NotificationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 0
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NotificationCell

    return cell
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {

}
}
```

The cell is just UICollectionViewCell, there I have a UIView, UILabel and UITextView.

This is how I get to the VC from the Tabbar:

```
  let notificationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NotificationVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
```

I now only see the background on my VC, but the cell itself won't show.

Comment: 0 sections is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NotificationCell
```

As from your code it seems that you have to change `reuseIdentifier` to `cellId`?

and you are returning 0 in `numberOfSections` instead of 1 in your case

Answer (score 1):

if You set 0 section then collectionview never display any section of your View..so change sections as per your coding..for check now change section 0 to 1 in this method..

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you create your collectionview is wrong width, height. Because when you set frame equal zero, it mean that your width and height of collectionview equal zero too. It due to coloection never display.
 You should set width and height for it bigger zero. At that time you will see collectionview display